# Angularjs ui-grid - exported excels cell formatting

Tags: angularjs, excel, cell, angular-ui-grid

I am exporting the json data through angularjs ui-grid to the excel format.
I see few formatting properties for pdf , but not for excel. Could someone help how to format the excel cell of this exported csv. Or if the formatting can be done at all .

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by formatting options? If you mean style etc. that is not possible with csv format. If you want to select rows / columns see this example in the docs. http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Unfortunately, this is not a default option. A CSV is simply a text-only format, with no specification for including metadata.

I've not done this, but believe that you could probably put something together with a bit of effort using what [Brian Hann has outline in his blog](http://brianhann.com/easily-import-spreadsheets-into-ui-grid/), and the [UI-Grid exporter service](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.exporter.service:uiGridExporterService). While what he has outline is the inverse of what you want, having an example of the two libraries together should help get closer to the solution.

On a side note, if you are not doing any paging with the grid, you could create an exporter outside of the grid, knowing that $scope.gridOptions.data will contain your source. There is a basic example of how to get the data into XLSX format here: [Exporting an array to excel file with cell formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548378/exporting-an-array-to-excel-file-with-cell-formatting).

```
XLSX.writeFile($scope.gridOptions.data, 'grid_export.xlsx');
```