# Error when use a library - javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, js-xlsx

I use [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) library. I need to write an excel file. So when I defined a `wb` variable as excel workbook and asked `js-xlsx` to write it to same file

```
XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'out.xls');
```

I get an error at browser console:

```
require.js:900 TypeError: Cannot read property 'writeFileSync' of undefined
```

XLSX.writeFile turns to [js-xlsx/dist/xlsx.js row 1340](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/blob/master/dist/xlsx.js#L1340)

```
_fs = require('f'+'s');
```

And when I paused it to debug, _fs is undefined, of cource. I can't see where I could find 'f' or 's' libs.  Please help me to understand it.

Comment: Are you running it in browser?

Comment: @Maxx yes, it works with browser

Comment: No, it's not. You can't write file with browser, your code should be run under nodejs

Comment: @Maxx That's not what their [README](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) says... `"In the browser: <script lang="javascript" src="dist/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Really? Their readme says "**nodejs** write to file: `XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'out.xlsx');`"

Comment: have you tried using XLSX.write() as it's shown here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548378/exporting-an-array-to-excel-file-with-cell-formatting

Comment: @bfmags and Maxx - thanks for help - XLSX.writeFile is really for node.js and XLSX.write successfully work in browser. Maybe you add this info as answer?

Comment: Thnx, I will :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `XLSX.write`-- *writeFile* function is specific to nodejs

---

- `XLSX.write(wb, filename)` write to binary string **(->browser)**
- `XLSX.writeFile(wb, filename)` **nodeJS** function

---

```
/* XLSX.write(wb, 'out.xls'); */

/* bookType can be 'xlsx' or 'xlsm' or 'xlsb' */
var wopts = { bookType:'xlsx', bookSST:false, type:'binary' };

var wbout = XLSX.write(workbook,wopts);

function s2ab(s) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
  var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (var i=0; i!=s.length; ++i) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
  return buf;
}

/* the saveAs call downloads a file on the local machine */
saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:""}), "test.xlsx")
```

https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx#user-content-writing-workbooks